# Move (not copy) files from server to a local computer

Tags: bash, shell, scp

I have a file on the Linux server that I want to move (not copy) to my local computer. However, I did something like as below after reading commands from stack overflow, however it just copies the file and doesn't move it.

```
scp -r obs@180.78.5.547:/home/obs/folder/test.txt       /home/yuan/folder/
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

*"Moving"* is essentially copying and then deleting the source file.

If you want to *"move"* a file over the network, you have to do just that.
This is always preferable, since should the network connection fail, you can retry copying, without losing any data (should your files have been transferred improperly, but deleted afterwards).

Once the files are transferred, you have to delete the source files on the server, for instance with:

```bsh
ssh obs@180.78.5.547 'rm /home/obs/folder/test.txt'
```

The option `-r` you used in your example, is for copying files recursively, which suggests you want to copy directories of files over the network. I suppose you want to *move* all files over the network (transfer and then delete all files inside that source directory).

When copying or *"moving"* files between two machines, I suggest using [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). It will only transfer new and changed files, and skip identical files already at the destination. It has an option to remove source files in one go, after they've been transferred, which should mimic the behavior you presumably expect when *"moving"* a file from one machine to the other:

```bsh
rsync -aPEmivvz --remove-source-files obs@180.78.5.547:/home/obs/folder /home/yuan
```

And for just one file you'd use:

```bsh
rsync -aPEmivvz --remove-source-files obs@180.78.5.547:/home/obs/folder/file.txt /home/yuan/folder/
```

Using the `--remove-source-files` option simply deletes the file(s) after they've been transferred.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Did this work for you? it so click the ✓

Answer (score 8):

`rsync` has a `--remove-source-files` option.  It removes all synchronized non-dir files.

This would probably work:

```
rsync -avz --remove-source-files obs@180.78.5.547:/home/obs/folder/test.txt /home/yuan/folder/
```

Note rsync needs to be installed on source and destination machines.

Try running with `--dry-run` to make sure it works before running it.

The nice thing about `rsync` over `scp` is that it can copy file permissions, ownership, symbolic links, use compression to speed up transfers over slow connections, and perform hashes to verify that the transfer was successful before deleting.

I normally use `rsync` for backups where it will only transfer files which have changed since the last sync, saving lots of time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

`scp` won't remove anything from the server, you can run `rm` on the server when `scp` was successful:

```bsh
scp -r obs@180.78.5.547:/home/obs/folder/test.txt /home/yuan/folder/ \
  && ssh obs@180.78.5.547 'rm /home/obs/folder/test.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

### There is no spoon.

Despite the word 'move' meaning 'move' in English.  That's not what it does in computers. the mv command was only created to ameliorate your human fixation with physical objects.

Rename, is more apt.  This is why rename and mv are interchangeable.  Moving a file from one directory to another on the same filesystem simply 'renames' the file with a new full name including the new path.

Think of files like a simple two column vertical list on a sheet of paper.  The path is on the left and the file contents on the right.

"moving" just erases the left column and writes a new value.  The contents of the file didn't "go" anywhere.  A filesystem is the binder in which these pages reside.

When you think you're moving a file from one filesystem or another (including from one computer to another) **you're not**.  What you're doing is copying it from one to another, then "erasing" it on the first.  (which of course isn't really erasing it either, just *forgetting* it.)

**It is not the file that moves.  *It is only yourself.***